# What are Test Projects in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, test-project

I am moving from 2008 to 2010 to try out some of the C++0x features but I noticed that there are test projects in 2010, what are these and how can I use them in my environments?

Answer (score 1):

These are projects that define the Unit Test code for the other projects in your solution.

Comment: So is this similar to this example: having a separate project (static library) which can be compiled with a separate driver project (only containing winmain.cpp)?

For instance: I have a vector math library that I want to test with a variety of client drivers: console applications, DirectX applications, etc.